# Same file name from node_modules and from my own project

Tags: html, build, web-component, rollup

I have a project that uses translation so the file structure looks like 'assets/translations/*'. The node module that I am using also uses the same file structure so when rollup copy the files and puts it to '/dist/assets/' it first copies the one from node_modules then the one from my project. The problem is that it overwrites the translations from node_module and causes issue with the component from that package.

The end result that I need is for both translations (en.js) file to merge in the dist folder so both the node_module and my package can refer to its values.

Tried merge and copy from rollup but no luck or I was using it wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: @TiberiuC. no, I'm using javascript.